# Manipulated SVG-Node after browser DOM-Update not visible

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, dart, polymer

I wasn't able to come up with a better question title than this one. If you have one, feel free to edit it.

Anyhow, I'm currently writing a SVG manipulator in Dart and Polymer and it worked out pretty good so far. However, when I try to wrap a SVG element in another one the browser will update the SVG element in such a way, that it's not visible any longer.

Example:

SVG before the manipulation. All elements are visible and displayed correctly.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="446px"
     height="788.605px" viewBox="0 0 446 788.605" enable-background="new 0 0 446 788.605" xml:space="preserve">
    <g><!-- some content --></g> <!-- wrap this element in another one -->
    <g><!-- more content --></g>
</svg>
```

SVG after the manipulation.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="446px"
         height="788.605px" viewBox="0 0 446 788.605" enable-background="new 0 0 446 788.605" xml:space="preserve">
    <g><!-- wrapper -->
        <g><!-- content not visible anymore --></g>
    </g>
    <g><!-- content still visible --></g>
</svg>
```

The code for the manipulation looks like this (Dart):

```
  Element _createWrapper(Element element) {
    Element wrapper = new Element.tag('g');
    var parent = element.parent;
    int idx = parent.children.indexOf(element);
    wrapper.append(element);
    // insert wrapper at the original element's position
    // in its parent
    parent.children.insert(idx + 1, wrapper);
    wrapper.append(element);

    // if I use softReload() everything is visible again
    //svg.softReload(); 
    return wrapper;
  }

  void softReload() {
    if (_svg != null) _svg.remove();
    _svg = new SvgElement.svg(_svg.outerHtml);
    $['container'].append(_svg);
  }
```

As stated in the comments, the SVG is displayed correctly when I make use of my softReload() method. However, I find it extremly ugly to do such a 'soft reload' and thus I would like to ask not only for a better solution but also why this problem occurres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create SVG elements via [SvgElement.tag](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:svg.SvgElement#id_SvgElement-tag) and not Element.tag At the moment you're creating a HTML element with a tag name of `g` rather than an SVG `<g>` element.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much, you made me really happy today!!